# Converting from float (IEEE754) to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, ieee-754, bitconverter

I'm using IEEE754 format to communicate some values via TCP. In this example, I'm converting an int to a byte[], and then using BitConverter to convert it to a float (already in IEEE754 Single format, 32-bits).

I need to take this float and store it into a byte[4], but without going back to its original value (which would not be encoded in the specified format). BitConverter.GetBytes() autommatically does that, which is why I cannot use it.

```
int volumeInt = (int)(volumeTest);
byte[] volumeTank = new byte[4];

volumeTank[0] = (byte)(volumeInt >> 24);
volumeTank[1] = (byte)(volumeInt >> 16);
volumeTank[2] = (byte)(volumeInt >> 8);
volumeTank[3] = (byte)(volumeInt >> 0);

float volumeFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(volumeTank, 0);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

Context:
The reason I'm doing this is to encode the byte[] as ASCII and include it in a string that will be sent via TCP. It has to be in IEEE-754 format, and it has to be encoded in ASCII. Though the answer I was looking for was only how to convert a float to a byte[].

Example:

Given an int : 9876. It can be converted to IEEE754 format as a float: -8.380858E-27. Now, I want this value stored in a byte array, without losing the format and going back to its original value (9876).

Comment: What do you mean "Without going back to its original value"? and what do you mean encoded? Do you mean the endianess? Or do you mean that this should work `int -> byte[] -> float -> byte[]`, but `float -> byte[] -> int` shouldn't work? I don't really get your scenario or what you're trying to achieve or even why?

Comment: By "original value" I meant "not in IEEE754 format". I meant the same by "non-encoded", I know it's not the best word to use in this case.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you show input, output and wanted output.

Comment: Okay, so you don't want it in the `IEEE754` format, but you didn't specify what format you want it in then.

Comment: Your approach makes little sense -- all "small" integers (up to 2^24) can be represented exactly as IEEE 754 floats, but not all bit patterns of 32-bit integers are valid floats, and if you try to treat them as such, you're going to run into trouble. Under your scheme, `49407` would be encoded as a NaN, and good luck round-tripping that. You can convert a float to bytes, but don't try to stuff an integer directly into those bytes and then pretend it's a valid float. I can't quite tell from your question whether the `int` is relevant at all here.

Comment: Similarly, with: "it has to be encoded in ASCII": Do you mean it has to be transformed to Base64 or hexadecimal or similar and then encoded as ASCII? You can't interpret arbitrary bytes values as ASCII since ASCII code units have a range of only 0-127.

Comment: @TomBlodget what I meant was transmitting "0x41 0x30 0x31 0x30" instead of "A0A0", for example. That part is not important really, it was only meant to give some context to the situation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, that's a good point. No, the "int" part is of no importance at all. I was casting it from a decimal type in my attempt to convert it to a byte[], but it's really not relevant. Do you have a suggestion in this case?

Comment: It's still really unclear from your description why `BitConverter` doesn't do what you want. It can go from `float` to `byte[]` and back. If the order of bytes doesn't match, that's easily fixed. .NET adheres to the IEEE 754 format, so that can't be the problem either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert perhaps you can tell me if my concept is wrong. In a float, or System.Simple type, the data will be arranged in the IEEE754 format, which is 1 bit for the sign, 8 bits for the exponent and 23 bits for the mantissa (32 bits total). If I use BitConverter.GetBytes(), it won't return those 4 bytes I just mentioned, since it will return the correspondent number in bytes, but will not mantain the format. Even though both occupy 4 bytes, the values are different.

Comment: You may be confused by the fact that `BitConverter` uses the native format of the platform, which (for x86) is little-endian. The float `3.1415927f` has the logical bit pattern `0 10000000 10010010000111111011011` (spaces to separate the parts for clarity), which, grouped by bytes, is `01000000 01001001 00001111 11011011`, or (in decimal) `64 73 15 219`. Reverse these bytes for endianness, and lo: `BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 219, 15, 73, 64 }, 0)` gives a delicious slice of π.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oooooh I see! Indeed, my concept was wrong. If anything, I could just reverse the byte array. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the format, let's say you have an agreement about BigEndian. Also here in [online hex converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) which can help to see the different representation of hex string:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float f = 9876f;
        var bytes = GetBigEndian(f);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", f, BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", f, GetFloatFromBigEndian(bytes));
    }

    static byte[] GetBigEndian(float v)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(v);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }

    static float GetFloatFromBigEndian(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes); // We have to reverse
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```